# PHP login, sign in button refreshes page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

Hello I am currently trying to implement a PHP login system onto my website,I am following this guide: 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_mysql_login.htm'

I have followed this guide exactly but it dosn't seem to be working.

whenever I hit the sign in button is just seemed to refresh the current page although I have told it to go to my index2.php page.

I was wondering if anyone would be able to guide me to fix this. Thankyou in advance.

Here is the PHP at the top of my login.php:

```
<?php
   include("config.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE email_adress = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {

         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

         header("location: index2.php");
      }else {
         $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
      }
   }
?>
```

Here is the html form in login.php:

```
<h2 class="section-heading">Login Form</h2>
                                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action = "" method = "POST">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="username" class="control-label sr-only">Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="username" name = "username" placeholder="Email">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="password" class="control-label sr-only">Password</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <label class="fancy-checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox">
                                                <span>Remember me</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Sign in</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <br>
                                <p><em>Don't have an account yet?</em> <a href="#"><strong>Sign Up</strong></a>
                                    <br>
                                    <em>Forgot your password?</em> <a href="#">Recover Password</a></p>
```

Here is session.php:

```
<?php
   include('config.php');
   session_start();

   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select email_adress from customer where email_adress = '$user_check' ");

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $login_session = $row['email_adress'];


   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("location:login.php");
   }
```

?>

Comment: going to  `index2.php` is after successful login. Are you sure the login was done?

Comment: No i think this is my problem but i cant seem to workout

Comment: Did you want to compare `$login_session` (in session.php) against `SESSION['login_user']` ? what is `$login_session` for?

Comment: AFter all I think the answer below solves your problem. You forgot to set action for your form.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action = "[THIS MUST BE SET]" method = "POST">
```

Your form action="" isn't set.

Comment: yes I dont think you have to if the php script is in the same file. either way i tried setting it and it still seems to not be working